# Rendering 1000+ View Elements is slower than expected

Tags: react-native

In React Native I have a Screen that shows a short story consisting of up to 1500 words. These words are clickable (and can have a border) so each one of them is wrapped in a View and TouchableOpacity.

The performance when opening the screen is way slower than I expect it to be, rendering a Screen with 1400 Words can take up to 5 seconds. Doing the same things in vanilla js on a website takes far less than a second.

This is my code. I have an array 'content' containing all the words and in the render function I use map to loop over them and create the TouchableOpacitys/Views.

```
return (<View style={styles.hanziRow2}>
    {content.map(word => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpcaity onclick={() => this.openWord(word)}>
          <View style={[styles.hanziBlock, { backgroundColor: 'transparent', paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }]}>
            <Text style={styles.hanziBlockUpper}>{word}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpcaity>
      )})
    }</View>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its obvious that the performance will be slow because you are rendering a lot of TouchableOpacitiy components at once.
So in order to fix it, you should limit the number of components that are rendered on the screen at once.And its quite obvious also that why would you like to render those components which ain't visible on the screen at that time.
For implementing it, you can use Flatlist component to limit the rendering.
It will increase the performance of you app.

Comment: Removing the TouchableOpacity and only rendering the Views doesn't really improve the performance. Using Flatlist does not make sense, since (per default) it renders 21 viewports simultaneously, and a short story with 1400 words only takes up 3-4 viewports.

Comment: I'm just suggesting to use flatlist as it will allow you to render only those stuff on the screen which is visible to user. For additional info you may refer the site:
https://medium.com/sanjagh/how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist-946490c8c49b